# ios - NSFetchResultsController error with sortDescriptors

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have a Table View Controller with a list of Formations handled by a fetchResultsController.

Here's how my core data entities looks like :

[image]

I try to sort my fetchResultsController by `dateRange`like this :

```
// |fetchedResultsController| custom setter
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.mainManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateRange" cacheName:kFormationsFetchedCacheName];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

// |fetchRequest| custom setter
- (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest {
    if (_fetchRequest != nil) {
        return _fetchRequest;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student == %@", self.currentStudent];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateRange" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

    _fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:kBSFormation];
    _fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    _fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dateDescriptor, nameDescriptor, nil];

    return _fetchRequest;
}
```

Everything is fine when i try to add the very first `Formation`, but for the next ones, i have these errors:

```
2013-01-30 22:43:08.370 [7202:c07] -[BSDateRange compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81781a0

2013-01-30 22:43:08.371 [7202:c07] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[BSDateRange compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81781a0 with userInfo (null)

2013-01-30 22:43:08.372 [7202:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BSDateRange compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81781a0'
```

If i comment this line : `NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateRange" ascending:NO];`, it's working but my table view is messy as  the `sectionNameKeyPath` is set to `dateRange`

Someone is figuring out what's the problem here ? :/

Comment: First thing that jumps out is that you're trying to sort on a relationship and not an attribute?

Comment: Yep, dunno if this is allowed but as i'm using this relationship for my section too, i thought i had to sort with this same relationship to get my table view properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to sort based on the `dateRange` relationship. But `dateRange` is a relationship to `BSDateRange`, and how does Core Data compare those? Should it use `from`, or maybe `to`, or some combination of those? You can't just tell it to sort on an object like that, because it's not obvious how sorting should work.

Instead, **first** figure out what sorting even means. Then modify your sort descriptor appropriately. For example if you decide that sorting depends on the `from` value, change the sort descriptor to use the key path to `from`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateRange.from"
    ascending:NO];
```

If you need to sort based on both `from` and `to`, use more than one sort descriptor.

Comment: Actually i already tried with `date.from` and `date.to` but my table view is still messy :/ But maybe the problem come from sections ... Can i use a relationship for declaring my section ? (`sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateRange"`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have the same problem using `dateRange` for sections. The `NSFetchedResultsController` needs to sort the sections, but how does it sort `dateRange` instances? Also, keep in mind that the docs for the section name say that *"If this key path is not the same as that specified by the first sort descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same relative orderings."* You need a sortable section name key path. I don't know what happens if you pass something it can't sort.

Comment: Ye i ended up with adding a `name' attribute to my 'dateRange' entity and sorting / sectioning my fetchResultsController with this attribute. Thx for your help Tom.